# Como eu faço um trigger para a validação do angular-input-masks?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, front-end, datepicker

Tenho um campo :

```
<input type="text" name="DataNascimento" class="form-control data"
    ng-model="EscolherCurso.DataNascimento" required ui-date-mask/>
```

que preferi usar o datepicker do jquery. Porém quando o jQuery preenche o valor, o angular não executa a validação de novo.

Tentei usar o evento do datepicker :

```
onSelect: function (dateText) {
        $(this).val(dateText);
            if ($(this).valid()) {
                $(this).removeClass('invalid').addClass('success');
            }

    }
```

mas não bombou.

Comment: Testa disparar `.trigger('input');` nesse elemento

Comment: Não deu certo pra mim não, tentei trigger('input'), trigger('change'), triggerHandler('change') ... e nada

Comment: Testaste `$('[name="DataNascimento"]').trigger('input');` dentro desse `onSelect` e não funcionou?